# JS move point by an angle on circle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have program where I click three times, each click creating a point on canvas. I then calculate angle between those three points like this:

```
function find_angle(A, B, C) {
    var AB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x - A.x, 2) + Math.pow(B.y - A.y, 2));
    var BC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x - C.x, 2) + Math.pow(B.y - C.y, 2));
    var AC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(C.x - A.x, 2) + Math.pow(C.y - A.y, 2));
    return Math.acos((BC * BC + AB * AB - AC * AC) / (2 * BC * AB));
}
```

[image: degree]

In example picture above, the calculated angle is 93°. I need to move `point 3` by -3° so the points make exactly 90°. I have this function for it:

```
var angleToCorrect = alpha * (Math.PI / 180) - 90 * (Math.PI / 180);
correct_angle(point2, point3, angleToCorrect)

...

function correct_angle(p2, p3, angle) {

    var x = p2.x - p3.x;
    var y = p2.y - p3.y;
    var r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y); //circle radius. origin of the circle is point 2


    return {
        X: p2.x + (Math.cos(angle) * r),
        Y: p2.y + (Math.sin(angle) * r)

    };

}
```

Now, this function should return new `x` and `y` for `point 3` with corrected angle to 90°. Yet the coordinates don't agree with what I expect. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _the coordinates don't agree with what I expect_ - Please provide us with an input and an expected output.

Comment: The point you have calculated is `angle` degrees from the x axis, not the line through p2 and p3.

Comment: If `angleToCorrect` is the calculated angle to apply to the points to correct your angle, we should need to know what is `alpha`, how it is calculated and if its value is right, to start.

Comment: @Kaddath The alpha is presented in the image.

Comment: However, given also that a vector-based approach is probably more useful: what is the original problem you're trying to solve? For instance it would be much easier to limit the placement of the third point so the angle will always be 90° from the start.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm trying to achieve what you are suggesting - Click three times and draw third point always in 90° - so correct user input. But your idea to limit placement is interesting

Comment: Does the length of the line between points 2 and 3 need to be preserved? Or should the length match the length of the line between points 1 and 2?

Comment: @J.Stott not sure if I understand your question. But basically I need to create circle with origin in point2 and radius of length of the line between points 2 and 3 and them move point3 along this circle

Comment: Yes, but isn't there an incoherence between your parameters and the image? Why do you try to correct `point2` and not `point3`?

Comment: @Kaddath `p2.x` and `p2.y` in the return object is offset of the circle origin, which is point 2

Comment: @Kaddath I am not trying to move `point 2`. the returned `X` and `Y` from function `correct_angle` are new coordinates for `point 3`

Comment: sorry your last comment was not very clear, see @ChrisG comment then

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/j68Lrexm/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you for the link, this might be exactly what I need, gonna play with it now and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the new position it isn't enough to provide just two of the points since the angle is measured between the three.

So inside this function you have to figure out what the current angle of the vector between point 1 and point 2 is. Javascript offers a nifty built-in function for this `Math.atan2()`
Now that we know the angle (in radians) we need to add the new angle to it. This makes sure we can place point 3 correctly.

```
function correct_angle(p1, p2, p3, angle)
{
    var currentAngle=Math.atan2(p1.y-p2.y, p1.x-p2.x);

    currentAngle+=angle;

    var x = p2.x - p3.x;
    var y = p2.y - p3.y;
    var r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

    return {
        X: p2.x + (Math.cos(currentAngle) * r),
        Y: p2.y + (Math.sin(currentAngle) * r)

    };
}
```

The angle parameter of the function should be the target angle in radians (90 or 1.5707963267949 in your case)

Here's an interactive example:

```js
Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

var pointA = new Point(162, 39);
var pointB = new Point(105, 161);
var pointC = new Point(211, 242);

var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

function correct() {
  var newPoint = correct_angle(pointA, pointB, pointC, 1.5707963267949);
  pointC.x = newPoint.X;
  pointC.y = newPoint.Y;
  draw();
}

function correct_angle(p1, p2, p3, angle) {
  var currentAngle = Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x);

  currentAngle += angle;

  var x = p2.x - p3.x;
  var y = p2.y - p3.y;
  var r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

  return {
    X: p2.x + (Math.cos(currentAngle) * r),
    Y: p2.y + (Math.sin(currentAngle) * r)

  };
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(pointA.x, pointA.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(pointB.x, pointB.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(pointC.x, pointC.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="background-color:#dddddd;"></canvas>
<button onclick="correct()" style="float:left">
correct me
</button>
```

Comment: Your example with 90 degrees works only if I draw my points from upper left corner in counter clockwise direction. If I want to draw for example from upper left corner in clockwise direction, then the target angle is 180 degrees. Is there some easy way to tell if the target angle is 0, 90, 180 or -90 degrees? Or I must somehow remember in what succession I draw the points?

Comment: The correct_angle function should work no matter if the vertices are ordered clockwise or vice versa. I'd say your find_angle function needs to take care of that.